# Sum and product of a rational and irrational number

Tags: real-analysis

If we have $a$ as some rational number, and $b$ as some irrational number, then are the following two always true?

i) $a+b$ is always irrational

ii) $ab$ is always irrational

I know for ii) it is false, we can let $a = \frac{0}{1}$ for example, and then $ab \not \in \mathbb{I}$. But For $a \not = 0$ this is true however. Although my book does not specify any restriction on $a$.

I feel i) is always true.

Is this the result of rational numbers being closed under addition and multiplication? Or is there something else at play.

The proof is not too difficult by contradiction, I know. I am just wondering if there is a "reason" per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine with the second part, but maybe this will help for the first part (Arpit's hint is really what you want do here; I'm just filling in the details):

**Claim:** Suppose $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational. Then $a+b$ is irrational.

*Proof.* Suppose $a+b$ is rational (proof by contradiction). Then
$$
a+b=\frac{p}{q},\qquad p,q\in\mathbb{Q}\space\text{(and $q\neq 0$)}.
$$
Thus, we have the following:
$$
a+b=\frac{p}{q}\Longleftrightarrow b=\frac{p}{q}-a\Longleftrightarrow b=\frac{p-a}{q}\Longleftrightarrow b=\frac{m}{q},
$$
where $m=p-a$ and $m$ is a rational number due to closure of addition/subtraction in $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, $b\in\mathbb{Q}$, but this is a contradiction. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks for this, who do you refer to when you say Arpit?

Comment: @elbarto A user with that name initially left a comment suggesting you use contradiction. I see that person deleted his/her comment.

Comment: ah right, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that (ii) is false if $a = 0$ and (ii) is true if $a \neq 0$. Indeed, this is because $\mathbb Q$ is closed under (nonzero) divisions. If we suppose instead that $ab \in \mathbb Q$, then since $a \in \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$, it follows that $b = \frac{ab}{a} \in \mathbb Q$, a contradiction.

Likewise, (i) is true because $\mathbb Q$ is closed under subtractions. If we suppose instead that $a+b \in \mathbb Q$, then since $a \in \mathbb Q$, it follows that $b = (a+b) - a \in \mathbb Q$, a contradiction.

Comment: Got it, thanks!